# DevExpress control not appear in toolbox, not in "Add new item" too

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress, toolbox

I am using Devexpress 12.2.7 in Visual Studio 2013, it's work OK. After uninstalled and reinstalling  DevExpress, everything come to crash, I cannot see any Devexpress control in toolbox, neither in "Add new item". 
I ran Devxpress repair, no work
Uninstall an reinstall DevXpress, no work
Uninstall and reinstall VS, not work

How can I fix this?

Comment: Right click on the control's toolbox -> Choose Items -> Check all the DevExpress controls. Done!

Comment: Thank @Gusman, but what about "Add new item..."?

Comment: You mean the DevExpress forms? It will only work if it's installed with devexpress. Did you tried the ToolboxCreator tool which comes with DevExpress explicitly to do that? Also, I'm not sure if DX12 "works" with Visual Studio 2013, I have myself the DX11 and it does not install anything, it only works up to VS2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the [Visual Studio Support History](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument17003) help topic. According this document, DevExpress components of version 12.2 cannot be used with Visual Studio 2013. The cause of such limitations is that newer Visual Studios have a different registration mechanism for add-ins, thus you can't use the "Add new item" add-in.
Anyway as far as I know many VS2013-compatibility issues were fixed in version 12.2.15 to supports Visual Studio. So at-first I suggest you upgrade to the latest version of v12.2 (12.2.18 for now).
Then (if some issues with toolbox remains) you can try [the solution based on manual tuning of some registry keys](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q508209).